# The plt.colorbar is not corresponding to the image color

Tags: python, heatmap, colorbar

I am doing with the heatmap of one CNN model. *cv2.applyColormap* is used to tranfer the heatmap into color, and it is shown by *plt.imshow*. I want to add a colorbar in the image. But when I use *plt.colorbar()*, the colorbar is not correctly corresponding to the color in image. The following is partial code.

[image]

```
heat_map = np.random.randint(0,255,size=(50,50))
heat_map = heat_map.astype(np.uint8)
plt.figure()
covered_heat_map = cv2.applyColorMap(heat_map, cv2.COLORMAP_JET) 
covered_heat_map = covered_heat_map/255
a1 = plt.imshow(covered_heat_map,alpha=1)
plt.xticks([])
plt.yticks([])
plt.colorbar(a1)
```

Comment: Please provide the code or a value for the heatmap variable.

Comment: Thank you. I have added a random array as heatmap variable.

Comment: The colour bar seems to perfectly correspond to the matrix. There are no issues.

Comment: I add the output image I run.  The red color in the image doesn't apprear in the colorbar. Is this result the same with yours?

Comment: Yes, it is the same. I believe the red is in the lower end of the colorbar.

Comment: The *heatmap* is transfered from *cv2.COLORMAP_JET*. If the colorbar is correct, it should be same with the color distribution of COLORMAP_JET. But it is totally different. So I think the range of colorbar is not right.

Comment: Technically everything seems correct, as covered_heat_map has max = 1 and min = 0.

Comment: Thanks for your attention. But I still think there would be something wrong. And I find a lot of people to make confirmation.

Comment: No worries, good luck. Cheers

Comment: I don't know, I haven't used cv2's colormap feature, but isn't a heatmap an arbitrary colormap representation of the values of a 2D array, which is an array converted from array to color information? I thought it was showing the default color map for that array. `plt.imshow(..., cmap='jet') `

Comment: @r-beginners Thanks. When adding *cmap='jet'*, the image is shown correctly. Although the image displayed is right, I am still confusing. I think the right displaying is because *cmap='jet'*  forces the colorbar to show a same color range with the image. However, shouldn't the color bar automatically extract the color range from the image for display?

Comment: If you check the contents of the data for `heat_map` and `covered_heat_map`, you will understand.

Comment: @r-beginners Thank you. I will learn about this.